# Load view controller without displaying nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiviewcontroller, facebook-login

I have a button that presents a view controller containing login elements including a Facebook login button. Once the user logs in successfully the view controller is automatically dismissed and user returns to the previous screen.

I am trying to implement an auto login feature whereby cached tokens can auto login i.e. the user does not have to tap the button which presents the secondary view. Currently the logic around checking for cached tokens works fine, and once I load the view it instantly logs in and removes the view without me having to do anything. However I want to be able to trigger this without actually showing the view itself. Is there a way to show the view but make non visible? Or how are such scenarios meant to be implemented?

Currently I have

```
self.loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
self.loginVC.delegate = self;
self.loginVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:self.loginVC animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

Comment: In which method(s) does the login occur?  If it is all done in `viewDidLoad` then you can force load the view but just accessing it (`self.login.view`) in place of the `presentViewController`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class `LoginAuth` that performs only the network calls for login authentication.
2. whenever you want `loginVC` to show up, awake the nib , call the `LoginAuth` and perform dismiss on successful authentication.
3. For auto login, directly call the `LoginAuth` for authentication via cached tokens in background; if that is successful go ahead, else show the `LoginVC` for logging in again

Comment: I agree with Amisha. (Voted.) A view controller object is for displaying and managing views. If it happens to include some other methods, that's ok, but it does not make sense to create a view controller that isn't going to display anything. It makes more sense to split out your logic into 2 different objects, an authentication object and a login view controller object, and write them to work together.

Comment: problem is fb login is triggered by a view and the logic is all abstracted away. the only thing I need to specify is the delegate which is the original vc and only gets called after login.